# select distinct aplicado a 1 sola columna

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hola tengo este query

```
query = "select distinct nombre, precio_coste, precio_venta from tabla_productos where precio_coste <> ''";
```

necesito aplicar el **select distinct** a la columna **nombre** para solo mostrar los **nombres** distintos, ya que **precio_coste** y **precio_venta** pueden repetirse pero el nombre debe ser unico,

Comment: Para tener un listado de nombres únicos deberías colocar solo nombre seguido de DISTINCT. Las demás columnas precio_coste, precio_venta quitarlas. Podrías colocar un ejemplo de como esperas el resultado. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) de está forma:

```
SELECT 
    nombre, 
    group_concat(precio_coste) as precios_coste, 
    group_concat(precio_venta) as precios_venta 
FROM 
    tabla_productos 
WHERE 
    precio_coste != ''
GROUP BY nombre
```

Posteriormente como estás trabajando en Php, puedes recorrer el resultado de la consulta y para cada nombre obtendrás una cadena de los precios de coste y los precios de venta con los valores separados por ",", que podrás separar en un array con la [función explode](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php).

La parte de Php, utilizando PDO, podría ser

```
$pdo = new PDO(...);

$stm = $pdo->query($sql);
$ar_data = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($ar_data as $f) {
    $nombre = $f['nombre'];
    $ar_precios_costes = explode(',',$f['precios_coste']);
    $ar_precios_ventas = explode(',',$f['precios_ventas']);
    
    echo $nombre . "\n";
    echo "Precios costes \n";
    foreach($ar_precios_costes as $pc) {
        echo "\t $pc \n";
    }
    
    echo "Precios venta \n";
    foreach ($ar_precios_ventas as $pv) {
        echo "\t $pv \n";
    }
}
```